# UML Code generation tool in C#

Tags: c#, uml

Please suggest me any opensource tool to generate C# code from UML designer,Or any plugin to generate code from visualstudio. My requirement is to have a code generation tool for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate C# code from [Visual Studio's class diagrams](http://www.developingfor.net/visual-studio/visual-studio-2008-class-diagram.html). You can either click on your project and add a new Class Diagram or select View Class Diagram from the drop down if you would like it to model what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

We used [MagicDraw](http://www.magicdraw.com/) & [Maven C sharp plugin](http://maven-csharp.javaforge.com/project/11) in the past with much success.

Of course, there's also Enterprise Architect - but it isn't open source.